# How come when I insert into the token column the code doesn't work, but when I just insert into user_id it actually stores the data?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code that does not insert anything into the table:

```
        $cstrong = True;
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
        $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
        DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens (token, user_id) VALUES (:token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>$token, ':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

Now when I remove token from all this, the code works:

```
        $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
        DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens (user_id) VALUES (:user_id)', array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

Here is the query function:

```
        public static function query($query, $params =array()) {
        $statement=self::connection()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        
        if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my token column but I do not know what. In Sequel Pro, I have token as type CHAR with a length of 64, and it has a unique key. Token is not unsigned and does not allow null.

Comment: try run the query straight on the mysql and see what error u get.. pretty sure your column length for your token is way too short

Comment: you need at least 128 column length for your token.. btw why you use `bin2hex` function? that function is used to convert binary data to hex representation.. using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is more than enough to generate token or you can simply concat your token with `uniqid` to make it even unique